# How to download audio file?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, swift3

I want to download audio files (mp3, m4a, wma...) with Google Drive API. Trying following code, I got the error on simulator.

**Error:**

```
The operation could't be completed. (The user has not granted the app xxxx read access to the file alEnlflseiFNSEi.)
```

**Code:**

```
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/\(identifier)?alt=media"

service.fetchObject(
    with: URL(string: url)!,
    delegate: self,
    didFinish: #selector(GoogleDriveFileListTableViewController.downloadWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
)
```

---

```
// Parse results and display
func downloadWithTicket(ticket : GTLServiceTicket, finishedWithObject response : GTLDriveFileList, error : NSError?) {
    if let error = error {
        showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your "read access" problem here's what the [Download files states](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#using_altmedia):

> Downloading the file requires the user to have at least read access.
>   Additionally, your app must be authorized with a scope that allows
>   reading of file content. For example, an app using the
>   drive.readonly.metadata scope would not be authorized to download the
>   file contents. Users with edit permission may restrict downloading by
>   read-only users by setting the viewersCanCopyContent field to true.

Try obtaining the webContentLink of the audio file using [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get#try-it). When this link is clicked or opened in a new window, the audio file will be downloaded.

It looks something like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bzgk4zccNwI7TzBxZTFzbHFhdUU&export=download
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it.
And I found mistake. Don't need ?alt=media in URL.

Comment: I check response from web.